# CakePHP Relation on link

Tags: php, cakephp

The following link is used in a list of Favours! It links to a place where the user is from but is being used inside the favour list Hence the favour variable.

I have three models Users, Places and Favours. A user has many favours and one place, a favour belongs to a user.

```
<?php foreach($favours as $favour): ?>

<p><?php echo $this->Html->link($favour['User']['firstname'] . ' ' . $favour['User']['lastname'], array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'view','userName'=>$favour['User']['username'])); ?> in <?php echo $this->Html->link($favour['Place']['name'], array('controller'=>'places','action'=>'view',$favour['Place']['id'])); ?> asked a favour <?php echo $favour['Favour']['datetime']; ?></p>

<h3><?php echo $this->Html->link($favour['Favour']['title'], array('controller'=>'favours','action'=>'view',$favour['Favour']['id'])); ?></h3>
```

How do I display the link as at the moment I get an error saying that Place is undefined.

This is the controller action for that list:

```
function index()
{
    $favours = $this->paginate();

    if (isset($this->params['requested']))
    {
        return $favours;
    }
    else
    {
        $this->set('favours', $favours);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you contain Place when fetching data for Favour.

Comment: ? I have no idea what that means :(

Comment: I'm still very confused :/ Could you post an answer with some code perhaps? Thanks

Comment: in controller pr( $favours) and then check that "Place" array is available or not.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it should look like in your favours_controller:

```
function index(){
    $favours = $this->Favour->find('all');
    $places = $this->Favour->Place->find('all');
    $this->paginate();
    $this->set(compact('users', 'places');
}
```

This is how it should look like in your index.ctp:

```
<?php foreach($favours as $favour): ?>
<?php echo $this->Html->link($favour['Favour']['username'], array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'view', $favour['Favour']['username'])); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php foreach($places as $place): ?>
<?php echo $this->Html->link($place['Place']['place'], array('controller'=>'places','action'=>'view', $place['Place']['place'])); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

You may also need to define the `uses` variable:

```
var $uses = array('Place');
```

Comment: Did you read the question? :) The problem is that their is no direct relation between a Favour and a place. A place is connected to a user and a user is connected a favour so when I display a list of favours I'm only able to do the relation between it and the user and not pull the place information!!

Comment: @Cameron I've updated my question. I misunderstood what you ment.

Comment: Thanks but I'm not listing places ;) I'm merely showing the place of the user so it reads for each Favour like `Cameron in Huddersfield asked a Favour on 9th October 2011` so Cameron is the Favour author and Huddersfield is the place that is linked with that author.

Comment: I don't think it is possible if you dont have a straight relation between favour and place.

Comment: What about that Contain stuff that's mentioned by Ivo? Any ideas on how that could help?

Comment: What I would do is create a relation between favour and place. Many favours may belong to one place. So in this case you would have place_id in your favour table. That would be the solution.

Comment: But the place is specific to the user and not the favour!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4147/discussion-between-piotr-chabros-and-cameron)